# WideCharToMultiByte fails randomly with error 122/ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER

Tags: c, winapi, unicode, utf-8, c-strings

I have created a small application in C that encrypts and decrypts a string using the caesar cipher. After a string (unicode) has been decrypted, it gets converted to UTF8 using WideCharToMultiByte. It works around 90% of times, but sometimes the the WideCharToMultiByte seems to fail and the GetLastError function prints 122 which means ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER.

My function for converting the unicode strings to UTF8 looks like this:

```
LPSTR convert(LPWSTR wideStringToDecryptAndConvertUTF) {

   LPWSTR res = shift(wideStringToDecryptAndConvertUTF, -6); //Decrypting the string by shifting -6 letters.

   MessageBoxW(NULL, res, L"Decrypted output", MB_OK); //Check if the string was successfully decrypted - judging by the output of the messagebox this is always the case, the decrypted string looks as expected.

   LPSTR retVal = 0;
   ULONG cb = 0, cch = (ULONG)strl(res);
   cb = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, res, cch * sizeof(WCHAR), retVal, cb, 0, 0);
   retVal = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_FIXED, cb);
   WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, res, cch * sizeof(WCHAR), retVal, cb, 0, 0);

   if (GetLastError() == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER) {            //Check for debugging purposes. At random times (even with the same string) this specific error occurs.
       MessageBoxW(NULL, L"Error", L"Debug", MB_OK);
   }
   GlobalFree(res);
   return retVal;
}
```

My shift function to decrypt/encrypt strings looks like this (in this case it gets decrypted):

```
LPWSTR shift(LPWSTR shift, int param) {

    LPWSTR allc = L"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz[]<>()[]";
    LPWSTR encrypted = (LPWSTR)GlobalAlloc(GMEM_FIXED, strl(shift) * sizeof(WCHAR) + 1);
    int r = 0;
    if (encrypted != NULL) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < strl(shift); i++) {
            r++;
            if (strchr42a((LPWSTR)allc, shift[i]) != NULL) {

                LPWSTR e = strchr42a((LPWSTR)allc, shift[i]);
                int index = (int)(e - allc);
                encrypted[i] = allc[index + param];

            }
            else {
                encrypted[i] = shift[i];
            }
        }
    }

    if (encrypted != NULL) {
        encrypted[r] = 0;
    }
    return encrypted;

}
```

Although this is quite simple, here's the strl function used in both functions above:

```
size_t strl(LPWSTR s) {
    size_t i = 0;
    while (s && *s != '\0') {
        s++;
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}
```

All strings I try to encrypt have been encrypted using the same program and only consist of letters.
I know that the encryption itself has limitations (for example you can't shift more than 8 letters when encrypting), but that's not my problem.
I don't understand why the WideCharToMultiByte function seems to work unstable in my case. Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: Pay attention to the arguments. The fourth argument to WideCharToMultiByte is **never** a byte size-calculation; it's a simple magnitude (i.e. a number of wide characters being converted), or `-1` if the string is known-terminated and you just want WCTMBS to do the calculation for you. The `sizeof(WCHAR)` you have has *nothing* to do with that number, and shouldn't be there. Furthermore, take care that when you specify exact length, WCTMBS does *not* include space for the terminator if you need one, so you also have to add that in to the size of your target buffer allowance.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. However, if I remove the sizeof(WCHAR) it seems that the string termination fails. If I check the return value of the convert function the output sometimes is the decrypted string + some garbage characters.

Comment: Didi you read the *Furthermore* in that comment? And incidentally, since these strings are (supposedly) terminated anyway, `strl` is pointless to use in instance, just send `-1` as the fourth argument and let WCTMBS do the length calculation including the terminator for you.

Comment: Thank you so much! Im currently still testing but it seems to work now. It's always those small details that I get stuck with in C...

Comment: Documentation certainly helps : [WideCharToMultiByte](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-widechartomultibyte).

Comment: There is no such thing as a *"small detail"* in C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `WideCharToMultiByte` incorrectly.  The 4th parameter is a **character count**, not a **byte count**.  You are also not null-terminating the `retVal` buffer, and not doing any error handling at all.

Also, `shift()` is calculating the wrong byte size for its `encrypted` buffer.  And worse, if the input `shift` string contains any character `A..F`, the found index being offset by `-6` will go out of bounds of `allc`.

Try something more like this:

```c
LPCWSTR strchr42a(LPCWSTR str, int ch)
{
    do {
        if (*str == ch) return str;
    } while (*str++);
    return NULL;
}

LPWSTR shift(LPCWSTR shift, int param) {

    LPCWSTR allc = L"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz[]<>()[]";
    ULONG shift_len = strl(shift);

    LPWSTR encrypted = (LPWSTR) GlobalAlloc(GMEM_FIXED, (shift_len + 1) * sizeof(WCHAR));
    if (!encrypted) return NULL;

    int r = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < shift_len; ++i) {
        ++r;
        LPCWSTR e = strchr42a(allc, shift[i]);
        if (e != NULL) {
            int index = (int)(e - allc) + param;
            if (index < 0) {
                // OUT OF BOUNDS! Need to wrap the index, or fail the function...
            }
            encrypted[i] = allc[index];
        }
        else {
            encrypted[i] = shift[i];
        }
    }

    encrypted[r] = 0;
    return encrypted;
}

LPSTR convert(LPWSTR wideStringToDecryptAndConvertUTF) {

   LPWSTR res = shift(wideStringToDecryptAndConvertUTF, -6); //Decrypting the string by shifting -6 letters.
   if (!res) {
       MessageBoxW(NULL, L"Error", L"Debug", MB_OK);
       return NULL;
   }

   MessageBoxW(NULL, res, L"Decrypted output", MB_OK); //Check if the string was successfully decrypted - judging by the output of the messagebox this is always the case, the decrypted string looks as expected.

   ULONG cch = (ULONG) strl(res);
   ULONG cb = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, res, cch, retVal, 0, NULL, NULL);
   if (cb == 0) {
       DWORD errCode = GetLastError();
       MessageBoxW(NULL, L"Error", L"Debug", MB_OK);
       return NULL;
   }

   LPSTR retVal = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_FIXED, cb + 1);
   if (!retVal) {
       DWORD errCode = GetLastError();
       MessageBoxW(NULL, L"Error", L"Debug", MB_OK);
       return NULL;
   }

   WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, res, cch, retVal, cb, NULL, NULL);
   retVal[cb] = 0;

   GlobalFree(res);
   return retVal;
}
```